# XML Serialization Parent Elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have to serialize data from my application to XML, but it has to conform to the existing format, for example:

```
<Microsoft>
   <Office>
     <Students>
            <Student Name="Blah" />
      </Students>
   </Office>
</Microsoft>
```

Or something like that, where Student is the entity I am serializing and I need to tell it to go as a child of Microsoft/Office. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a Microsoft object and a Office object.

For example:

```
public class Microsoft
{
    public IList<Office> Office {get; set;}
}

public class Office
{ 
    public Student CurrentStudent {get; set;}
}
```

This will deserialize to a MS object with a list (1 or more) Office object.  Each Office node will have 1 and only 1 student object.

Comment: Thanks, I did just consider this but it does seem like there should perhaps be a way to control it through attributes or something perhaps?